# Log4j2 stops logging to log file after clearing log file

Tags: log4j2, weblogic12c

I am running my application on a WebLogic within a Linux environment. after clearing the content of the log file using `">log4j2.log"`. my application stops logging at all.

I have tried restarting my application, and then the server but still no logs.
also tried deleting the file using rm -f and then doing the restart but still no logs. see the config below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" monitorInterval="60">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileAppender"
                     fileName="./PortalLogs/log4j2.log"
                     filePattern="./PortalLogs/log4j2.log.%i.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
                     immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %-5p [%X{messageExtTxt}] [%c] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <RegexFilter regex="*DefaultMessageListenerContainer*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" level="ERROR" >
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender" level="INFO"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I tried using delete from WinSCP instead and then restarted the server, the log files were again produced and with logs in it.

My question is that is there a way to clean the log files safely without causing this issue? thanks in advance!

EDIT: Linux's RM on the log file before restarting the server actually works and recreates the log file, but still is there a way to make it work using ">log4j2.log" or after modifying the file? we need this as we have a protocol to do an initial run for automated tests, clear everything and then do an actual run.